# Linux Alternative app to Jasc Paint Shop Pro -- specificaly with similar "Workspaces" like feature

Tags: workspaces, gimp

I am trying to find a Linux alternative to Jasc Paint Shop Pro... so long as the alternative has a similar kind of specific functionality.

Jasc Paint Shop Pro has a specific feature called "Workspaces" that I find extremely helpful!

Here is how I use "Workspaces" in Paint Shop Pro (and the kind of functionality I am hoping to find in a Linux app):

JascPSP's photo editing capabilities I do use only I am lite user. I prefer editing using Jasc's advanced configurable features over apps like MSPaint or GIMP. (confess, not well versed in GIMP).

I much am an incredibly heavy user of JascPSP for viewing photos!

I typically use JascPSP to open A TON of images and when I have a huge boat load of images opened I like to "save the Workspace".

Re-opening a saved "workspace" reopens every photo that was open... also restores window positions, and likely a lot more things that I have not used yet.

JascPSP tickles my fancy because it saves things to actual files (settings, thumbnails, and most importantly the "workspaces" too). The saved "workspaces" files are viewable in notepad++ (plain text, hex64 or something).

Is there any Linux Alternative photo viewing app that has a similar feature to "workspaces" that can be re-opened and easily reload all the photos?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know why you tag this "Gimp" because what you describe is a photo management app, and Gimp is essentially a picture editor. There are some apps that can do photo management on Linux, try gPhoto or DigiKam. Not sure their database are just plain text files, but then if needed the format is described somewhere.

Comment: I only tagged gimp because my perspective has gimp cited as a default defatcto "just-as-good" challenger to other photo editor software titles.